# How can I filter my GEE data to only look at bounds specified by a GeoJSON file?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, geemap

Forgive me if this is a noob question... because I am one.

I have the following snippet to load some Landsat data:

```
dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T2_L2').filterDate('2017-06-01', '2017-07-01')
```

However, this looks at the whole globe (as expected). I have a GeoJSON file which provides a bound for the area I actually care for. What would be the best way to go about it? The `filterBounds()` function doesn't allow for that object type.

Ideally I do this prior to all the rest of my processing, which is going to be huge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can try is converting the GeoJSON file to a FeatureCollection using the assetID. Later you can use the filterBounds.

```
aoi = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/file")
dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T2_L2').filterBounds(aoi)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to upload a GeoJSON as an asset. HOWEVER, I used [this](https://mapshaper.org/) to turn it into a zipped shapefile, uploaded that, and your snippet worked!